# How to get color at XY pos from screen raylib

Tags: c++, raylib

I want to make Minecraft with Raylib and are trying to add the cursor but can't get the color at the center to see what color to make the cursor.

I tried some code (It's at the bottom) but i always get 0,0,0 for rgb I want 255,255,255 if I am looking at white on the center of the screen etc..

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;
    const int screenCenterX = screenWidth / 2;
    const int screenCenterY = screenHeight / 2;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - 3d camera first person");

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        Image screenImage = LoadImageFromTexture(LoadRenderTexture(screenWidth, screenHeight).texture);
        Color pixelColor = GetPixelColor(screenImage, screenCenterX, screenCenterY);
        UnloadImage(screenImage);

        char text[50];
        sprintf(text, "R:%i G:%i B:%i", pixelColor.r, pixelColor.g, pixelColor.b);
        DrawText(text, 10, 10, 20, BLACK); // Ensure the text color is contrasting

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```